# Laravel fix N+1 Query issue

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have following code in `AppServiceProvider` class:

```
    Model::preventLazyLoading(! $this->app->isProduction());

    Model::handleLazyLoadingViolationUsing(function ($model, $relation) {
        Bugsnag::notifyError("N+1 Query detected", sprintf("N+1 Query detected in %s::%s", get_class($model), $relation));
    });
```

I have following query:

`select * from units where units.id in (1) and units.deleted_at is null`

which runs in two functions. When the page is executed laravel throws N+1 exception because it thinks this query runs more than once, however this query was called from two different functions and both serves different purpose. The only case it doesn't throw exception when one of the function has more than one units and `unit.id` changes. How can I fix N+1 issue? This is a false alarm.

Comment: The error is likely not because Laravel thinks the query runs more than once but rather because it lazy loads the relationship in one of the two code locations e.g. you have `$model->relationship->property` somewhere and the relatioship is not already loaded at that point. Laravel doesn't count how many times a relationship was loaded specifcally it just triggers the handler if a relationship was accessed without having been loaded before.